# How to redirect a method call?

Tags: c#, reflection, replace, .net

I have got a DLL which works fine in Windows, but Inside one of its private functions the static System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes() is called. I have to use this DLL on a windows CE smart Device Project with Compact Framework 3.5 and there is no such method in the System.IO.File. I have tried to create a class named "File" inside the project like this:

```
public class File
{
     internal static byte[] ReadAllBytes(string path)
     {
     }

     internal static void WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
     {
     }
}
```

My own calls to the static Methods of the class File are redirected here But the calls inside the DLL methods still go to the System.Io.File class and I still get the MissingMethodException. I tried the methods with public modifiers but saw no change.

I even tried to rewrite the public method that calls the private method inside which the ReadAllbytes was invoked and used MethodInfo.Invoke with no success.

The question: Is there a way to force the method inside the Dll to accept my ReadAllbytes Method instead of System.File.IO.ReadAllBytes()? The invocation inside the DLL is like this:

```
using System.IO.File;

namespace Something
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        public Boolean someMethod()
        {
            byte[] myBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply change the code of the DLL and recompile it?

Answer (score 0):

Static methods like File.ReadAllBytes are resolved at compile time to a specific Assembly name and class. You will need to modify the DLL to change the call. Prehaps you could decompile and recompile it, or edit the IL.

*It is possible to redirect the call using the profiling hooks (the sameone the debugger uses), and that is how the Moles Mocking framework works. However it would not be suitable for production use.